# Best way to provide an InputStream from an ImageInputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, javax.imageio

I have an `ImageInputStream`. I'm using a third-party API that requires an `InputStream` source. I wrote a wrapper class to pass to the API:

```
class ImageInputStreamWrapper extends InputStream {

    private ImageInputStream imageInputStream;

    public ImageInputStreamWrapper(ImageInputStream is) {
        imageInputStream = is;
    }

    public int read() throws IOException {
        return imageInputStream.read();
    }

}
```

It works, but it's extremely slow. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to add:

```
public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    return imageInputStream.read(b, off, len);
}
```